# asking about basic javascript line by line

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I understand JS code is executed line by line. Why then in the code below `alert` is performed before `hide`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $("p").hide();
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Browsers don't necessarily re-do the page layout until the event loop (in this case, the event loop for the "click" event) finishes.

Comment: Because there are 2 type of actions you can do blocking for the UI thread and non blocking. In this case alert is blocking the UI thread and after you close the alert the UI is modified.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the DOM manipulations are usually a bit heavy and are rendered after all the statements in the mentioned event loop are executed.

As @Pointy rightly mentioned, the layout is rendered only after the registered statements are executed.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Answering the question would help me 

Answer (score 0):

It is executed after `hide()`. `hide()` registers DOM changes which will be executed after your commands are finished. You can wait for a little before you `alert`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $("p").hide();
         setTimeout(function() {
             alert("The paragraph is now hidden"); 
         }, 100);
    });
});
```